# Declare a const string from a resource

Tags: c#, resources, constants, resx

When I declare a const from a resx I have a compilation error.

```
private const string ERROR_MESSAGE = MyResource.ResourceManager.GetString("resx_key");
```

I understand why this compilation message occurs but is there a trick to declare a const from a resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because a `const` must be a compile time constant. Quoting the MSDN documentation:

> Constants are immutable values which are known at compile time and do not change for the life of the program.
>
> <sub>From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants</sub>

In your case the value is coming from a method invocation. So the result may not be known at the time of compilation. The reason for this is that the constant value is directly replaced into the IL code.

> In fact, when the compiler encounters a constant identifier in C# source code (for example, months), it substitutes the literal value directly into the intermediate language (IL) code that it produces.

So instead of `const`, you can use a `static readonly` here:

```
private static readonly string ERROR_MESSAGE = MyResource.ResourceManager.GetString("resx_key");
```

Comment: I know all that, but I can"t use readonly in my case because I need it for an attribute of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. The ValidationAttribute ErrorMessage of the Attribute Required must be a const. I know there are 2 others ValidationAttribute,  ErrorMessageResourceName and ErrorMessageResourceType, to solve the problem but it will not help me either, here is why :

Comment: @G.Dealmeida Okay, I'm not sure how you could do that. You might want to ask a new question with that information regarding the intended usage. You can link to this question for context, but try to include all necessary information in that question itself.

Comment: On a client-server application, I have a first project, common to both server and client side, where I have merged all the resources of all the projects of a solution. This project is referenced in another client-side project referenced in all client related projects. I dont want to referenced the project with the merged resources. The more I think about it and the more I am about to give up on the DataAnnotation, I will handle all the data validation business rules in the ViewModel directly

Comment: acutally, to this specific question you answered, as I was expected, "It's impossible". You also offered a work around, which is not relevant for my specific issue, but you can't guess from this simple question. Il will now marked this question as answered and I will review the architecture a bit. Thank you